# Get word position In document with lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I wonder how to get position of a word in document using Lucene
I already generate index files and I want to extract some information from the index such as indexed word, position of the word in document, etc

I created a reader like this :

```
public void readIndex(Directory indexDir) throws IOException {
    IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(indexDir);
    Fields fields =  MultiFields.getFields(ir);
    System.out.println("TOTAL DOCUMENTS : " + ir.numDocs());

    for(String field : fields) {
        Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
        TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
        BytesRef text;
        while((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
            System.out.println("text = " + text.utf8ToString() + "\nfrequency = " + termsEnum.totalTermFreq());
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the writer to :

```
org.apache.lucene.document.Document doc = new org.apache.lucene.document.Document();

                FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
                fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
                fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
                fieldType.setIndexed(true);

                doc.add(new Field("word", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8")), fieldType));
```

And I tried to read whether the term has position by calling **terms.hasPositions()** which **return true**
But have no idea which function can gives me the position??

Comment: Lucene 4.2 the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Before you try to retrieve the positional information, you've got to make sure that the indexing happened with the positional information enabled in the first place.

[TermsEnum.DocsAndPositionsEnum](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermsEnum.html#docsAndPositions%28org.apache.lucene.util.Bits,%20org.apache.lucene.index.DocsAndPositionsEnum%29)  : Get DocsAndPositionsEnum for the current term. Do not call this when the enum is unpositioned. This method will return null if positions were not indexed.

Comment: "Before you try to retrieve the positional information, you've got to make sure that the indexing happened with the positional information enabled in the first place"
How?

Comment: Simple: "Above method will return null if positions were not indexed.". I am not familiar with the latest version, but in the previous versions, we provide "Field.TermVector WITH_POSITIONS" to the Field constructr, or use Luke to examine the Lucene index whether the positional info is available.

Comment: In Lucene 4.x, you would pass a [`FieldType`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html) to the `Field` ctor, on which you have set `FieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);` and `FieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);` (`Field.TermVector` is deprecated).

Comment: @phani : Luke development already stopped. It doesn't recognize Apache 4.2

Comment: I'm sorry for being ambiguous, I mentioned that those two ways are for previous versions.

Comment: @phani : no problem, thanks for your explanation. I'm really confuse with Lucene 4.2 since its tutorial hard to find